# Corona SDK gotoScene function error

Tags: sdk, storyboard, coronasdk

When I try to open my game in Corona SDK I'm getting an error in function 'gotoScene'. My `main.lua` contains the following code:

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar ) 

local storyboard = require "storyboard"
storyboard.gotoScene( "start" )
```

Can someone please help me fix this error.

I am making the game Mark Falkland made in his youtube tutorial videos.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with your `start` scene. Make sure that your `start.lua` contains:

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

return scene
```

For more info, visit:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/newScene.html

Keep Coding............ :)

Comment: The compiler tells me its a problem with line 4 in main.lua. Specifically with gotoScene

Comment: It will say like that when you have errors in the next scene you are calling from that line(In your case: start.lua). If you want to confirm it, then just comment all lines in your 'start.lua', and add the above code to that page. It will surely remove the error...... :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous statement; the problem lies in your start.lua. If you open the Corona simulator and choose a new project -> multi-screen application with storyboard, the main.lua code that gets generated is this:

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
storyboard.gotoScene( "scenetemplate" )
```

(minus the commenting of course)

I believe that if you implement that structure that is found in the scenetemplate.lua, your project will run just fine. It is giving you the error at that line in your main.lua file because it cannot process farther than that (i.e. it cannot get into your start.lua file properly).